# set open terminal's title only by typing into same open terminal (no .bashrc edit)

Tags: command-line, gnome, scripts, gnome-terminal, 19.04

without closing and reopening terminal, without opening a new tab, without editing bashrc and without installing software nor already having added extra software that would not ship with Ubuntu 19.04.... How do you change an open  terminals tab using only commands typed into said open terminal tab.

Comment: This time I mean it. Your answer is in the accepted answer in the duplicate post.

Comment: did you TRY it?? it does not work in ubuntu 19.04!

Comment: This question is way too verbose. Stick to the point.

Comment: dude I ttired. the original first question I created was some 5 lines long. it was crystal clear.  it got mark as a dupe and downvoted into oblivion. they said they couldn't tell I was asking for something different then the dupe and asked to edit to clarify. I added and reformulated the context. not good enough. closed. I open this new one. this time I'm sure to be more explicit. same thing happens. I have to edit again. and here we are. dont downvote. just say you don't know or don't think it's possible. I dunno how I can get through this until all the community is in on it that it dosntwork

Comment: Yes I tried. Fully as described. Two little issues though: no colored prompt and sometimes, when arrowing up in the history, an extra "e" that would appear in the prompt. It is exactly what you are looking for: one command changes the current tab title; the window title changes as you change tabs. Also Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: does not change the title at all for me + the no syntactic coloring and bugged history

Comment: @tatsu please revisit the accepted answer to the called duplicate. I edited it to make it more clear.